# Python selenium: what is wrong with this code?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The code below is part of a selenium code to make a selection of games and then submit it... Sometimes, when odds changes occur, a new button "Accept Changes" gets in the mix and i have tried with this code below but still it doesn't work whenever odd changes occur. The script always stop at Accept Changes with exception. I need help please...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='j_stay']/div/div[3]/div/span/input").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='j_stay']/div/div[3]/div/span/input").send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='j_stay']/div/div[3]/div/span/input").send_keys('300')
time.sleep(2)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Accept Changes']]")
if len(elems) > 0 and elems[0].is_displayed():
    elems[0].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='j_buyer']/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[5]/button").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='j_buyer']/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[6]/div/div[2]/button[2]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='OK']]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='j_buyer']/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[5]/button").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='j_buyer']/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[6]/div/div[2]/button[2]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='OK']]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: you should include the exception you are getting and the html of the page when the exception occurs.  In general, these sleeps may be a bit of an issue.  You should probably use webdriverwaits with expected conditions instead.

Comment: What is the exception?  Also since you are repeating the majority of your if statement in your else block, why not just put your `elems[0].click()` in the if statement.  You don't really need to repeat all that code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like using your sleep is the problem here:

```
time.sleep(2)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Accept Changes']]")
```

You likely want to wait for something ... maybe for it to be displayed (tough to tell without more context.
Try this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()[normalize-space()='Accept Changes']]"))
element.click()
```

Comment: I get error with this below;    

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document